# Analytic solution to Linear Elliptic Equation with Special Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, closed-form, symbolic-computation

Is it possible to find the following 2D Laplace equation's analytical solution on the shadowed region when having such Dirichlet boundar condition:

$$\dfrac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0$$

[image]

I found there were already similar analytical solution results [here](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde301.pdf) to Laplace equation on a rectangular region, but that solution does not handle rectanglular regions with a rectangle hole in it.
[image]

With $a=50, u_0=0, u_1=100$ specified, for the rectangle region with a rectangle hole on it, it is also easy to find the numerical solution to such a PDE, which can be visualized as:

[image]

How can I obtain its analytical or explicit solution? or how to prove such an analytical/ explicit solution cannot be obtained?